# ffmpeg drawtext timecode changes duration

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, conversion, video-conversion

normally when I change framerates, I use Adobe Premiere and interpret video material as new framerate, so the duration changes. Thats fine. But because this is a mkv file I wanted to convert, I use ffmpeg.

But I have a weird problem with ffmpeg while adding timecode.

The code I am using looks like this:

```
/Applications/ffmpeg -probesize 50M -analyzeduration 100M -i "$f" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c:a pcm_s24le -async 1 -c:v dnxhd -b:v 36000k -r 25 -s 1920x1080 -aspect 16:9 -pix_fmt yuv422p -coder ac -trellis 0 -colorspace bt709 -color_range mpeg -subq 6 -me_range 16 -sc_threshold 40 -keyint_min 25 -g 50 -metadata creation_time=now -af atempo=1/0.95904 -vf setpts="0.95904*PTS" -vf drawtext="fontsize=30:fontfile=/library/fonts/tahoma.ttf: timecode='01\:00\:00\:00': r=25: x=main_w-180: y=30: fontcolor=white@1: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1" -sn -y "/Volumes/videos/$FILENAME.mov"
```

The created video is about 42min long.

When I render the video without drawtext:

```
/Applications/ffmpeg -probesize 50M -analyzeduration 100M -i "$f" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c:a pcm_s24le -async 1 -c:v dnxhd -b:v 36000k -r 25 -s 1920x1080 -aspect 16:9 -pix_fmt yuv422p -coder ac -trellis 0 -colorspace bt709 -color_range mpeg -subq 6 -me_range 16 -sc_threshold 40 -keyint_min 25 -g 50 -metadata creation_time=now -af atempo=1/0.95904 -vf setpts="0.95904*PTS" -sn -y "/Volumes/videos/$FILENAME.mov"
```

Than the rendered video duration is 40min59sec. That is the duration I wanted to and it's the same Adobe creates.

Why is the video duration, with the timecode drawed in the picture, longer than without?

How can I convert the mkv to a DNxHD with 25fps and burned-in timecode, using ffmpeg, the correct way, please?

Answer (score 0):

Your log says:

```
Multiple -filter, -af or -vf options specified for stream 0, only the last option '-filter:v drawtext' will be used.
```

Which means your setpts is being ignored and therefore the duration is longer.

Use only one `-vf` or use `-filter_complex` for both audio and video filtering:

```
/Applications/ffmpeg -probesize 50M -analyzeduration 100M -i "$f" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c:a pcm_s24le -async 1 -c:v dnxhd -b:v 36000k -r 25 -s 1920x1080 -aspect 16:9 -pix_fmt yuv422p -coder ac -trellis 0 -colorspace bt709 -color_range mpeg -subq 6 -me_range 16 -sc_threshold 40 -keyint_min 25 -g 50 -metadata creation_time=now -af atempo=1/0.95904 -vf setpts="0.95904*PTS,drawtext=fontsize=30:fontfile=/library/fonts/tahoma.ttf: timecode='01:00:00:00': r=25: x=main_w-180: y=30: fontcolor=white@1: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1" -sn -y "/Volumes/videos/$FILENAME.mov"
```

- You may have to change `timecode='01:00:00:00'` to `timecode='01\:00\:00\:00'`.
- See [Filtering Introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! So great, now everything is fine with the video length!

Comment: The only problem now is, that the audio is 109 samples shorter than the video lenght. The video and audio exportet with premiere has exactly the same lenght. Is there also a solution for that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jackspost New/different issues should be asked as new questions. Also, take a quick look at the [tour] if you want to increase your chances for getting an answer. Note that you're competing with other question askers because there are more questions than answers, so you need to understand how the site works for your advantage.